# How to prompt User to add gmail account programatically in android

Tags: android, android-intent, accountmanager

I am trying to add a gmail account from my app. I know we can't add the account directly and can just prompt the user to enter the credentials.
This is what I am doing.

```
// Get Account Manager
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get( _context );

// Adding abc@gmail.com using AddAccount and the intent  
Bundle userdata = new Bundle();
userdata.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, "abc@gmail.com");
try
{
    AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> amf = accountManager.addAccount
                        ("com.google", "mail", null, userdata, null, null, null);
    Bundle bundle = amf.getResult();
    Intent intent = (Intent)bundle.get( AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
    if ( intent != null )
    {
        _context.startActivity( intent );
    }
}
catch( Exception e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What my problem is I am getting the intent back after adding the account but this intent is not prompting to enter the credentials/ add the account or anything. It doesn't do anything. What I ideally want is when I start the activity, it should prompt the user to enter his/her credentials. How to achieve that?

Comment: `I am getting the intent back after adding the account` and `It doesn't do anything` ?? You add an account and it does not do anything?

Comment: No. I don't see the account in Accounts section

Comment: It is unclear to me what happens to the user and what not.

Comment: Are you expecting it to prompt for credentials on its own? Sorry I think that was the wrong method... I think you need something like `getAuthToken`?

Comment: When this is run, I get back the intent which I would assume means the account is gets created and I can use the intent to launch an activity to let the users enter their password. Atleast that is what I assumed from the documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager

Comment: @DigitalNinja You are right. I would assume it prompts for credentials when I launch the activity at _context.startActivity( intent );

Comment: `I get back the intent`. What you you mean by that? Please refer to exact lines in your code.

Comment: What happens is different on Android 4.0.3 and 5.0. On 4.0.3 it does prompt for credentials but asks for email address too. On 5.0 it shows the email address but it tells that Google does not recognise the address.The next button brings the same.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if it does automatically prompt for credentials... I was only speculating that you might need more code...

Comment: @greenapps Intent intent = (Intent)bundle.get( AccountManager.KEY_INTENT); This is the line I am mentioning about. and this is from the documentation "If no activity was specified, the returned Bundle contains only KEY_INTENT with the Intent needed to launch the actual account creation process."

Comment: @greenapps I am running on 5.0 devices and it does not do anything for me.

Comment: @DigitalNinja You are right.I just want to know what extra I need to do to prompt for credentials?

Comment: `Toast.makeText(context, "Exception: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG) .show();`. Put that in the catch block. Or Log() it. Did you put your code in a thread?

Comment: `it does not do anything for me`. Do you mean that startActivity() does nothing? (I asked you to refer to your code already).

Comment: I still think you need to call `getAuthToken`. From the documentation, "Gets an auth token of the specified type for a particular account, prompting the user for credentials if necessary. This method is intended for applications running in the foreground where it makes sense to ask the user directly for a password."

Comment: @greenapps I didn't get any exception and my code is in a class that is called from a Service. Yes the startActivity() does nothing.

Comment: What happens if you just call `startActivity(intent);`?

Comment: @everyone - My sincere apologies to both of you. It is my mistake. I did not add the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for the intent.